# Trigonometric Equation only works with specific input ( 5 ) doesn't work with other inputs

Tags: c++, trigonometry, cmath

I try to write code for that calculation angles from lengths of triangle. formula is
cos(a)=b^2+c^2-a^2/2bc. [(Triangle is here)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dxoqd.png)

```
angle1 = acosf((powf(length2,2) + powf(length3,2) - powf(length1,2)) / 2 * length2 * length3)* 180 / 3.14153;
angle2 = acosf((powf(length1,2) + powf(length3,2) - powf(length2,2)) / 2 * length1 * length3)* 180 / 3.14153;
angle3 = 180 - (angle2 + angle1);
```

Everything is float. When entered 5-4-3 inputs outcome this.

```
angle one is 90.0018
angle two is nan
angle three is nan
```

changing order doesn't matter, only gives output for 5.

Comment: First of all, if you want to do floating-point arithmetic use `double` instead of `float`. There haven't been a need to use `float` on normal PC-like systems for a long time. Secondly, see [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Comment: If my math is correct, `angle2` is trying to take arccos(7738), that's quite of out domain for that function

Comment: Are you missing parantheses around `2 * length1 * length3` maybe?

Comment: Also, `powf` is good for non integral exponents like 2.64. To compute x squared, use `x * x`

Comment: Pi is about 3.14159 not 3.14153? Or 3.141593? Or did you mean digits 767883 and the following from Pi?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are doing:

```
angle1 = acosf((powf(length2,2) + powf(length3,2) - powf(length1,2)) / 2 * length2 * length3)* 180 / 3.14153;
```

You should be doing:

```
angle1 = acosf((powf(length2,2) + powf(length3,2) - powf(length1,2)) / (2 * length2 * length3))* 180 / 3.14153;
```

**Explanation:** The problem is caused by the following formula, which is in fact badly written:

```
cos(a)=b^2+c^2-a^2/2bc
// This, obviously, is wrong because
//   you need to group the firt three terms together.
// Next to that, everybody understands that the last "b" and "c" are divisors, 
//   yet it would be better to write it as:

cos(a)=(b^2+c^2-a^2)/(2bc)
```

The brackets, I added in the code, are similar to the replacement of `/2bc` by `/(2bc)`.

Comment: Don't just fix the code, explain what is wrong, so it's useful for others. I.e. explain operator precedence.

Comment: @JHBonarius: you couldn't be more right, I've adapted my answer accordingly.